# Why is the NullPointerException raised after downloading a photo from a webserver?

Tags: php, java-me, lwuit

I am downloading a photo from a webserver. Here is the PHP code to display the photo in the web page url :

```
<?php
$rep = $_GET['dossierClient'];
    if (file_exists($rep))
    {
        $myDirectory = opendir($rep);

        while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
            $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }

        closedir($myDirectory);

        $indexCount = count($dirArray);

        sort($dirArray);

        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
        {
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
            {
                print("<img src=$rep/$dirArray[$index] />");
                //print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

In my javaME code I make a download from the PHP page :

```
Image tmpImage = downloadImage("http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/downloadphoto.php?dossierClient="+photoDirectory);
Image thumbImage = createThumbnail(tmpImage);
Button thumbButton = new Button(thumbImage);
thumbButton.setUIID("btnPhotoThumb");
thumbButton.addActionListener(this);
vButtonPhotos.addElement(thumbButton);
addThumbButton(thumbButton);
revalidate();
```

Here `Image` is referencing a LWUIT Image.
The code of the downloadImage() method is :

```
private Image downloadImage(String url) throws IOException
    {
        Image img = null;
        byte[] rawImg = null;
        try
        {
            String imageData = getDataFromUrl(url);
            rawImg = imageData.getBytes();
            putPhotoToPhone(rawImg);
            img = Image.createImage(rawImg, 0, rawImg.length );
        }
        catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return img;
    }
    public String getDataFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection c = null;

        long len = 0 ;
        int ch = 0;
        c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        is = c.openInputStream();
        len = c.getLength();
        if( len != -1)
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i < len ; i++ )
            {
                if((ch = is.read()) != -1)
                {
                    b.append((char) ch);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            {
                len = is.available() ;
                b.append((char)ch);
            }
        }
        is.close();
        c.close();
        return b.toString();
    }
private void putPhotoToPhone(byte[] rawImg)
    {
        FileConnection fcDir, fcFile;
        int photoId, photoNextCounter;
        String fileName;
        OutputStream os;
        if (rawImg != null)
        {
            try {
                fcDir = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDirectory+"/", Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if(!fcDir.exists())
                    fcDir.mkdir();

                if (vPhotosName.isEmpty())
                    photoNextCounter = 1;
                else
                    photoNextCounter = 1;
                    //photoNextCounter = getNextImageCounter(fcDir, String.valueOf(backForm.vPhotosName.elementAt(backForm.vPhotosName.size()-1)));

                fileName = "photo_downloaded_" + photoNextCounter + ".png";
                fcFile = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDirectory+"/"+fileName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if(!fcFile.exists())
                    fcFile.create();
                os = fcFile.openOutputStream();
                os.write(rawImg);
                os.close();
                fcFile.close();
                fcDir.close();

                try {
                    photoId = rsImage.addRecord(rawImg, 0, rawImg.length);
                    vRawPhotoIDs.addElement(new Integer(photoId));
                }
                catch (RecordStoreException ex) {}
                vPhotosName.addElement(fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

So the problem is at the `createThumbnail` method : the NullPointerException is raised when the application reaches this method. Even when I try to open the photo in the phone device then I get an "invalid format" error and the photo is not displayed.

Here is the code of createThumbnail() :

```
public Image createThumbnail(Image image) {
        int sourceWidth = image.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = image.getHeight();
        int thumbWidth = 50;
        int thumbHeight = -1;

        if (thumbHeight == -1) {
            thumbHeight = thumbWidth * sourceHeight / sourceWidth;
        }
        Image thumb = image.scaled(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
        return thumb;
    }
```

So how to make this download correct ?

Comment: I typed in the address bar of my browser this : http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/downloadphoto.php?dossierClient=RahajarsonMarvin , and I got a correct webpage which displays a photo. I right-clicked the page and I got its source code and it gave : <img src=RahajarsonMarvin/photo27.png />

Comment: I think you just answered your own question. Instead of an image, downloadphoto.php is giving you html that includes an <img> tag and the real path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your image simply fails to download, further causing parameter passed to `createThumbnail` to be null and NPE when you invoke `image.getWidth()` on that null parameter.

If you check the console (I guess you debug with emulator), you'll probably notice stack trace that comes from `e1.printStackTrace();` in *downloadImage method*. Check the information it tells you and try to figure what's going wrong in the download

Comment: I debugged it with the emulator and it is the Image.createImage which caused the problem.

Comment: @AndyFrédéric did you figure what kind of problem was in `Image.createImage`? Exception? or null `rawImg`? or something in length parameter? something else?

Comment: I found the solution !!! My error was in the setting of the url value : I googled about "j2me download photo" and I found a tutorial which shows the way to set the url. It is like this http://www.sitename.com/folder/imagename.png ; so the way I set my url in my code was wrong. And now it works fine after setting the right url !!! Thanks